# How to access files on remote PC from a Mac OS terminal?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, remote-connection

There have been a number of questions related to remote access PC from Mac, but I have not found an answer to my question.

I have a desktop at home and a Macbook laptop I'm traveling with. On my Mac OS terminal, given the my remote PC (a Window machine)'s IP/username/password (or any information), how can I access files on my remote PC from my Mac terminal?

The PC desktop will just be sitting unused - though connected to the internet, will not be clicked or operated. I do not want to install any fancy remote desktop GUI application. I do not need to see my desktop, as all I ever need to do is as simple as reading, writing or copying text files. Note: There is no ssh client installed on the desktop either, but I have ssh on OSX by default.

Neither of the two machines are server - they are both personal computers. Is it still possible? If not possible, what are the reasons?

Comment: How about setting up an FTP server on the windows system?

Comment: Didn't see the remote part first. So this means you're *not* in a LAN environment? As Daniel said, why not FTP, or rather, an SFTP-capable server? You'd just need to find out a way to track your IP, e.g. with DynDNS, and correctly forward the ports on your router.

Comment: I am away from my home desktop for few months... cannot touch the desktop until long after. Any alternative?

Comment: Exactly this? Set up a server and forward the necessary ports from your desktop PC. Access it from anywhere else. Otherwise, set up a [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) host (the unattended server module)?

Comment: "set up a server" do you mean I need to buy a new computer as server connected in LAN with the desktop?

Comment: You would have needed to ping me with `@slhck` for me to get a notification. Anyway, setting up a server means installing server software like FTP or SFTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TurboMeeting to do similar things when I am away. Mac control remote PC, transfer files, etc.

Just host a remote access session on your PC. Then you should be able to use your mac to access your home PC when you are on trip. TurboMeeting will reconnect automatically in case anything goes wrong at home. Also, you could reboot the PC remotely when you are away. The only thing you need to make sure is that keep your PC awak, don't let it go to sleep.